# How to get the index of the element selected in ListView JQUERYMOBILE

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have created a dynamic `listview` with a link with `id="a"`.

```
<ul id="accpmenu" data-role="listview" >
</ul>

$("#accpmenu").append('<li><a href='+ "#" + ' id="a" ">'+ this.textContent +'</a>  </li>');
```

Now i want to identify the index of the element that I have clicked from this `listview`.

```
$("#a").live("click",function(e)
{
    //What should i write here to get the selected index?.
}
```

I want the index number based on this I need to load the dynamic XML.

Please help me in resolving this.

Thanks
Shyam

Answer (score 7):

```
$('#accpmenu').on('click', ' > li', function () {
    var selected_index = $(this).index();
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w2JZU/

This will bind an event handler to the list-items in the `#accpmenu` list for the `click` event that finds the index of the clicked list-item (compared to other list-item elements).

On a side-note you have what appears to be some invalid HTML in your code:

```
$("#accpmenu").append('<li><a href='+ "#" + ' id="a" ">'+ this.textContent +'</a>  </li>');
```

Should change to (notice the removed double-quote after the id attribute):

```
$("#accpmenu").append('<li><a href='+ "#" + ' id="a">'+ this.textContent +'</a>  </li>');
```

My example above added the `click` event handler to the `li` elements since it is easy to ascertain the index of the clicked element but you can also bind to links in the list:

```
$('#accpmenu').on('click', 'a', function () {

    //this gets the index by finding the first parent list-item element and getting it's index compared do its siblings
    var selected_index = $(this).parents('li').eq(0).index();
});
```

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in the cases above replaces `.delegate()` (from earlier versions).

Here are some docs for ya to help explain the above examples:

- `.on()`: http://api.jquery.com/on
- `.index()`: http://api.jquery.com/index
- `.parents()`: http://api.jquery.com/parents

Comment: Hai, Thanks for the solution but this is not working to my problem as my pages are dynamically generated.in each page i have a listview in that listview if i click on anything then it should load a second page for that i am using changePage() here it is leading to second page(but not loading) and again i am populating the data for the second page.Your example snippet is valid for static list but its not working for the dynamic list which are loaded dynamically.

Comment: Hai Jasper, Earlier i use to call different html pages each and everytimes using change page ( $.mobile.changePage("aacp.html","slideup");)In this scenario it wasnt working Now i had replace all the code and kept in single file now this is working. can you let me know the reason why its not wokring for diff files though i am not calling external.